# Best Practices For Creating A Login Flow?

Tags: session, cookies, authentication

What is the best way to securely login in a user and keep the user signed in with cookies and sessions?

For example:

1. Check if password and email are valid for a specific user
2. Set a cookie with arbitrary string
3. Create a session with the same arbitrary string
4. Validate each request by the user by making sure the arbitrary strings of the cookie and session are the same

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to securly login in a user and keep the user signed in with cookies and sessions?

Using an established library.

Comment: Even the best libraries have abandoned an "all-in-one" solution kits. Google Sign in has discontinued Google Authentication platform (.signedIn(), etc...) and now are insisting services are implementing correct and knowledgeable handling of JWTs and parameters like sub/aud. From "You are now responsible for directly managing the signed-in status for users of your web app. Previously, Google Sign-In helped with Monitoring the user's session state." https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration Essentially the server should keep authorization and authentication solns separate

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define *"create a session"*. For our purposes here let's define this as *"create a server-side data store with an id and set a cookie with that id"*; i.e. what the default `session_start()` does. Then:

1. Ensure the connection is HTTPS.
2. Check login credentials.
3. If valid, create a session (see above) with a large, (pseudo-)random id and an expiration time as short as possible but as long as necessary. Security here comes from the fact that it's infeasible to *guess* suitably random session ids, so the longer they are and the shorter their window of validity is the better.
4. Store the id of the logged in user in the session.
5. On each page request, see if the session with the id from the cookie exists; if so, use the user id stored in it to get your logged in user.
6. Optionally storing and checking the user agent is not a bad idea; you should not check the IP address though, as that may change legitimately.

Answer (score -1):

Apart from storing it in sessions , you can also follow this method for keeping an user logged in , even after he closes the browser ->

1) Create a cookie storing user details and an unique hash
 
2) Create a sessions table (in a mysql db or any other db of your choice) where the unique hash is stored against the user-id, and the user agent of the browser,and the ip address .
3) Next time when the user logs in check that when the user logs in , is it from the same ip,same user agent .. If not , then delete the database entry , and repeat steps 1 and 2.

Apart from keeping an user logged in , it also gives you better security than just storing in sessions.

Comment: Never store any actual user details in the cookie, only meaningless opaque blobs!

Comment: By user details i meant , user name , and first/last name . Not passwords or any confidential data .